# How do I properly use a stored search radius with GeoFire?

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, firebase, geofire

I'm using GeoFire to search a given radius, which the user can set in my app and store on FireBase.  When the page loads, before running the GeoFire query I am getting the radius from Firebase.  However, when I run the code below, I get the following error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Precision must be less than 23!'

From playing around with some strategically placed print statements, it looks like the searchRadius is returning as 0 by the time the GeoFire query runs, leading me to suspect that asynchronous loading is at play.

My question is, am I getting this error due to my searchRadius being 0, and if so how can I ensure that the FireBase block that grabs my user's search radius runs before my GeoFire query?

```
    self.ref.childByAppendingPath("users/\(self.ref.authData.uid)/searchRadius").observeEventType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
        self.searchRadius = snapshot.value as! Double
    })

    let center = CLLocation(latitude: 37.331469, longitude: -122.029825)
    let circleQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, withRadius: self.searchRadius)



    circleQuery.observeEventType(GFEventTypeKeyEntered, withBlock: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in

        //Do code for each result returned

    }) //End GeoFire query
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is an async loading issue. Even if Firebase has already cached the value of `searchRadius` the value callback will not be executed inline. The thread will go on set up the GeoFire query before the value is updated.

Based on this code snippet, you can ensure that the radius is set before running the query by moving the query code inside of the callback. You may also want to observe a single event so that the query isn't run again if the value of `searchRadius` changes.

```
self.ref.childByAppendingPath("users/\(self.ref.authData.uid)/searchRadius").observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { snapshot in
    self.searchRadius = snapshot.value as! Double
    let center = CLLocation(latitude: 37.331469, longitude: -122.029825)
    let circleQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(center, withRadius: self.searchRadius)
    circleQuery.observeEventType(GFEventTypeKeyEntered, withBlock: { (key: String!, location: CLLocation!) in
        //Do code for each result returned
    }) //End GeoFire query
}) // End observeSingleEventOfType
```

Comment: Thanks!  Your explanation is much appreciated.